# how to read svn revision numbers from eclipse plugin

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin

Hy,

I'm trying to create a eclipse plugin that needs to see if version control is used and the version of a file.

I have noticed the .svn folders when svn is used, with informations about the files, but I think there has to be a better way then trying to read them manually.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a Subversion plugin for Eclipse that can give you this information.  (Actually there are two, Subclipse and Subversive.)  You could install those and retrieve the information from the plugin or just use the JavaHL library (The Java bindings for Subversion.) to retrieve the information programmatically.

Comment: hmm, JavaHL library sounds like a good idea. And I didn't know you can access data from another plugin.

Comment: Subclipse/Subversive get their information from the working copy.  If they have the data, you can get it from JavaHL the same way they do.  You wouldn't even need to query these plugins.  JavaHL is really easy to use and there are documented sources in the Subversion tree.